# Delete repeating column header in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python, I am iterating through a list in pandas, but I got the desire result except for it prints the column name each time.

```
 ServerIP HostName            Vulnerable_Package
0     10.1    apple  tar-(1.28-2.1ubuntu0.2+esm1)
  ServerIP HostName           Vulnerable_Package
0     10.1    apple  zlib1g-(1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.3+esm1)
  ServerIP HostName           Vulnerable_Package
0     10.1    apple   man-db-(2.7.5-1ubuntu0.1~esm1)
```

I expect  the output like below. How to achieve this?

```
 ServerIP HostName            Vulnerable_Package
1     10.1    apple  tar-(1.28-2.1ubuntu0.2+esm1)
2     10.1    apple  zlib1g-(1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.3+esm1)
3    10.1    apple   man-db-(2.7.5-1ubuntu0.1~esm1)
```

I use the code below.

```py
import pandas as pd
for i in range(len(vul_pkgname)):
    team = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(serverlist, hostname, vul_pkgname[i])))  
    team.columns =['ServerIP', 'HostName', 'Vulnerable_Package']
    print(team)
```

Answer (score 0):

You create and print a new `DataFrame` for each row, that's why you get multiple header.

Instantiate the `DataFrame` before the loop, add the headers, and then populate it using `append` within the loop.

```py
import pandas as pd
team = pd.DataFrame()
team.columns = ['ServerIP', 'HostName', 'Vulnerable_Package']
for i in range(len(vul_pkgname)):
    team.append(list(zip(serverlist, hostname, vul_pkgname[i])))
print(team)
```